# Azure cron pipeline always runs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up an Azure pipeline to run GUI tests twice a day. According to the documentation, it should only run if there have been code changes, but it always runs.

This is my cron schedule in "azure-pipelines-cypress.xml"

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 10 * * *"
  displayName: Daily 12:00 build (UTC 10:00)
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

Note that the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) states:

> always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last run. The default is false.

Is this simply a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Azure cron pipeline always runs

**Update2:**

> I don't want it to run every time the master branch is updated. It
>   should run when the master branch is updated AND only at a scheduled
>   time.
>
> But is that not the expected behavior of my current pipeline? The
>   current behavior acts as if I had set "always: true"

First of all, thanks Mick for your patience in providing a lot of detailed information.

Now, I figure out the issue and I could reproduce this issue on my side. If we set the scheduled triggers, but the build result is failed. In this case, even if we do not any change, the scheduled triggers will still fire. **That because the latest build failed, so the last commit record was not recorded by the pipeline**. When the scheduled time is reached, the last commit/source code change still exists. It will trigger scheduled triggers.

So, that the reason why your pipeline still executed, even if you do not do any change in the code/yaml.

If I successfully build the pipeline, the scheduled triggers works as expected.

So, it should be said that the documentation is not clear enough, it should be:

> always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there
>   have been source code changes since the last **successful** run. The
>   default is false.

I [submit this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6848) to MS, Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There have been no source code changes since thursday last week - it has ran twice a day since then. We have no created any new pipelines. The yml files are in the same repo as being tested - so no changes since thursday last week. No new branches since thursday (should that even matter when it's set to master?). There are no UI defined scheduled triggers.

Comment: @Mick, Isn't this exactly what was expected? So what is your problem now? What do you mean **pipeline always runs**?

Comment: I updated my previous comment. I would expect the pipeline not to run when there are no changes to our master branch.

Comment: @Mick, If understand you correct, you need change the trigger type to CI triggers instead of Scheduled triggers, check my updated answer for some more details.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I want. I don't want it to run every time the master branch is updated. It should run when the master branch is updated AND only at a scheduled time.

Comment: @Mick, Got it, make sense. This is the real question, you should update your question to make it clearer. I will check if there is any solution for this question.

Comment: But is that not the expected behavior of my current pipeline? The current behavior acts as if I had set "always: true"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205497/discussion-between-leo-liu-msft-and-mick).

Comment: @mick, Sincerely thanks for your detailed info, I could reproduce this issue, that because your build pipeline is failed. You could check my update2 answer for some details.Have a nice day.

Comment: it should even say if the previsous run completed and was successful. As if a run is long enough to still be occuring when the next is scheduled, the next starts.

Comment: Actually, I have scheduled a run every hour. The first run succeeds and the 'always' paremeter is false (since I don't set it in the yaml as this is the default) yet there is another run, and another etc. All successfull. So there is an issue.